# Why does this code output in reverse order?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

Why does the first code print DCBA and the second ABCD? Is 0x44434241 not equal to DCBA?

```
mov eax,4
push dword  "DCBA"
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,esp
mov edx,4
int 0x80
add esp,4

mov eax,4
push dword  0x44434241
 mov ebx,1
 mov ecx,esp
mov edx,4
int 0x80
  add esp,4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, no, and you even managed to find the proof of it :)

x86 is [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), the `0x44434241` numeric value is memory will be stored with 0x41 at the first byte location (lowest byte address), 0x42 at the second, etc.

Comment: and how DCBA store in memory and why?

Comment: "DBCA" is a byte array ("string"), not a number, it is stored in the order you write it regardless of endianness. (So `D` (0x44) is at the lower byte address.)

Comment: thanks.now i understand. 
so, every time i do some action on something in the memory, it take the value in order from the lowest byte location to the higher. right?

Comment: Not really, it does whatever you tell it to do (or whatever is documented for the opcode/function you're using). String operations will do that most of the time, yes. But some operations might not. For numerical operations, endianness matters and memory is read in blocks.

Comment: @user - We don't notice the endian-ness for byte operations, because a single byte only has one end.