# assembly-why the print is in reverse order?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

little endian:

```
mov eax,4
push dword  0x44434241
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,esp
mov edx,4
int 0x80
add esp,4
```

I don't understand why it print ABCD and not DCBA.
41 is in the lowest address and 44 is in the highest address, so why?
For example, when I write

```
x: dd 0x12345678
```

78 is in the lowest address but still the number here is not 78563412 but 12345678.

Comment: Little endian vs big endian issue? which would mean, it is ordered the other way arround, which would mean, it is doing what you have told it to do?

Comment: I'm confused by this question, you say 0x41 is in the lowest address and 0x44 is in the highest address, and that's correct, so why is there a problem?

Comment: That might be true @harold, but because of the endianness, it is processed the other way arround.

Comment: @MichaelOverhorst if it was processed the other way around I could see why the OP is confused, but it *isn't*, because he's printing it as text, and surely he's not asking why 41424344 (aka 0x44434241) is ABCD?

Comment: my confusion is becuse I don't understand what is the differnt between the code above to this: x: dd 0x12345678. In this example 78 is in the lowest byte, but still the number is 0x12345678.
In the example with ABCD, the lowest byte is 41 , so the number is 0x44434241 -> so why isn't it DCBA?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this code output in reverse order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283797/why-does-this-code-output-in-reverse-order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0x12345678` is a 32-bit value, which is represented on a little-endian system with the `0x78` at the lowest address (let's call that address `addr`), and the `0x12` at the highest:

```
 addr   addr+1  addr+2  addr+3                single 32-bit number
+----+  +----+  +----+  +----+                  +--------------+
| 78 |  | 56 |  | 34 |  | 12 |    represents    |   12345678   |
+----+  +----+  +----+  +----+                  +--------------+
```

and the 32-bit value `0x44434241` is stored with `0x41` at the lowest address, and `0x44` at the highest:

```
 addr   addr+1  addr+2  addr+3                single 32-bit number
+----+  +----+  +----+  +----+                  +--------------+
| 41 |  | 42 |  | 43 |  | 44 |    represents    |   44434241   |
+----+  +----+  +----+  +----+                  +--------------+
```

But the code in your first example is *not* using the memory as a 32-bit number: it is using the `write` system call to write *a sequence of bytes* to `stdout`.  This sequence of bytes is written in the order they are stored in memory:

```
 addr
+----+
| 41 |    =>   single byte 'A' is printed, then...
+----+

addr+1
+----+
| 42 |    =>   ...single byte 'B' is printed, then...
+----+

addr+2
+----+
| 43 |    =>   ...single byte 'C' is printed, then...
+----+

addr+3
+----+
| 44 |    =>   ...single byte 'D' is printed
+----+
```

Comment: +1 for ascii diagrams. How do you draw stuffs like this so well? any tools for that?

Comment: so...he should like use formatted output? so that the whole 4 bytes get considered at once? who will resolve the endianess then? just curious.

Comment: @Aftnix I had the same problem on iOS, and my solution was to just write everything in "backwards" so that it would read back in forwards ^^.

Comment: @Aftnix: it is the CPU that chooses how to consider multiple bytes as a single value of some larger width, when loading and storing.  If the sequence of bytes at `addr` is `0x41,0x42,0x43,0x44`, a *byte* load from `addr` into a register will always give the value `0x41`; a *16-bit* load will give `0x4241` for a little-endian CPU (or `0x4142` for a big-endian CPU); and a *32-bit* load will give `0x44434241` for little-endian (or `0x41424344` for big-endian).

Comment: @Aftnix: ...and I don't use any special tools for ASCII diagrams - just a text editor, with lots of copy-and-pasting!

Comment: so it means i can just use cpu's datatypes like dword quadword etc without much ambiguity. If i put something manually (load A immediate followed by a store word) into memory, it also should be handled by cpu. So machine works unambiguously, its the people who misinterprets? like this question?

Comment: @Aftnix: yes, if you always write and read back as dwords, there is no ambiguity; if you always write and read individual bytes, there is no ambiguity.  Endianness only becomes an issue when one piece of code treats the memory as a whole dword (or whatever), and some other piece of code treats the *same* memory as a sequence of bytes.  (Which is exactly what happens in this code: `push dword 0x44434241` writes a whole dword to memory, and the system call reads out a sequence of 4 bytes.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what is going on -> "The most common cases refer to how bytes are ordered within a single 16-, 32-, or 64-bit word, and endianness is then the same as byte order. The usual contrast is whether the most significant or least significant byte is ordered first—i.e., at the lowest byte address—within the larger data item."

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)